# PHP Append Array[0] in Recursive Function for Unknown Depth

Tags: php, json, xml, multidimensional-array, depth

I have xml that has been converted into array. The response array seems didn't create array[0] for one result, but create array[0], [1], [2] for many results. So I want to create array[0] for each one result response in order to standardize for my iteration. The initial response array as follow :

Array - One Detail

```
(
   [BookedDetail] => Array
        (
            [BookedDetailID] => 192            
            [Customer] => Array
                (
                    [CustomerID] => 110
                    [LanguageID] => 2                    
                    [Address] => Array
                        (
                            [StreetName] => Northway 23
                            [PostalCode] => 29843
                            [Region] => NSW
                        )
                )
            [Currency] => Array
                (
                    [CurrencyID] => 19
                    [CurrencyName] => Yen
                    [CurrencyShortName] => JPY 
                )
            [Status] => 1
            [CreateBy] => 15
        )
)
```

Array - Many Details

```
(
    [BookedDetail] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [BookedDetailID] => 192            
                [Customer] => Array
                    (
                        [CustomerID] => 110
                        [LanguageID] => 2
                        [CustomerType] => 1
                        [Address] => Array
                            (
                                [StreetName] => Northway 23
                                [PostalCode] => 29843
                                [Region] => NSW
                            )
                    )
                [Currency] => Array
                    (
                        [CurrencyID] => 19
                        [CurrencyName] => Yen
                        [CurrencyShortName] => JPY 
                    )
                [Status] => 3
                [CreateBy] => 16
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [BookedDetailID] => 193            
                [Customer] => Array
                    (
                        [CustomerID] => 113
                        [LanguageID] => 2
                        [CustomerType] => 1
                        [Address] => Array
                            (
                                [StreetName] => Southway 23
                                [PostalCode] => 2852
                                [Region] => SSW
                            )
                    )
                [Currency] => Array
                    (
                        [CurrencyID] => 23
                        [CurrencyName] => US Dollar
                        [CurrencyShortName] => USD
                    )
                [Status] => 2
                [CreateBy] => 17
            )
        )
)
```

My expected result :

```
(
    [BookedDetail] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [BookedDetailID] => 192            
                [Customer] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CustomerID] => 110
                            [LanguageID] => 2
                            [CustomerType] => 1
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [StreetName] => Northway 23
                                        [PostalCode] => 29843
                                        [Region] => NSW
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                    )
                [Currency] => Array
                    (
                        [0] = Array
                        (
                            [CurrencyID] => 19
                            [CurrencyName] => Yen
                            [CurrencyShortName] => JPY 
                        )
                    )
                [Status] => 3
                [CreateBy] => 16
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [BookedDetailID] => 193            
                [Customer] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CustomerID] => 113
                            [LanguageID] => 2
                            [CustomerType] => 1
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [StreetName] => Southway 23
                                        [PostalCode] => 2852
                                        [Region] => SSW
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                    )
                [Currency] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CurrencyID] => 23
                            [CurrencyName] => US Dollar
                            [CurrencyShortName] => USD
                        )
                    )
                [Status] => 2
                [CreateBy] => 17
            )
        )
)
```

Each node can have one or multiple child nodes so I want to make [0] for each node and [0][1][2]etc for multiple child nodes. I tried some code and have problem in maintain the current array result in order to add in recursive functions. Do I need variable outside function to store my current array, or append it while call the recursive function. My current code :

```
$x1 = json_decode(json_encode($xmlobj), true);
$result = array();
function callarr ($arrin)
{            
    foreach ($arrin as $arrkey => $arrvalue)
    {
        foreach ($arrvalue as $subkey => $subvalue)
        {
            if (is_array($subvalue))
            {                               
                $arr1[$arrkey][$subkey] = $subvalue;               
                // recursive function here
            }
            else
            {
                $arr2[$arrkey][0][$subkey] = $subvalue;
            }
        }
        $result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);                
    }
    return $result;   
}
$x2 = callarr ($x1);
print_r ($x2);
```

Result of $x2 will create [0] node under [BookedDetail] only since I haven't call the recursive function yet. I need help to get my expected array result. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It would help to have a sample XML file to convert.

Comment: Hi Nigel, thanks for your response. Sorry I'm newbie here. I try to copy my array after code $x1 = json_decode(json_encode($xmlobj), true); in this link : https://pastebin.com/v4vWVuw9 so for each node, it can be 1 result with no [0] and 2 or 3 results with [0][1][2] so if I don't do the standardization I have to check for each node if that's array or object, and I don't know how depth the arrays will be.

Comment: Hi - it would be easier with the XML source to work with.

Comment: Hi Nigel, I copy paste the xml in this link : https://pastebin.com/HYRsGTc5 sample with one and more than one items response. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know if this is exactly what you are after, but it may be easier for you to check it than me.

The function is now recursive, you can see where your comment has been removed and the assignment is being replaced by calling this function again with the `$arrvalue`...

```
function callarr ($arrin)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arrin as $arrkey => $arrvalue)
    {
        if (is_array($arrvalue))
        {
            $result[$arrkey][] = callarr($arrvalue);
        }
        else
        {
            $result[$arrkey] = $arrvalue;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nigel thanks a lot for your help. Your recursive function is correct, I added the "if (is_array($arrvalue) && !isset($arrvalue[0]))" so it won't create the new [ ] if there's already [0] inside it. Other thing that I missed is when the child is array there's no need to create [0]. So if [Customer]->[Address] there is no need to [Customer]->[0]->[Address]. Thank you very much if you have any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this but I doubt that array_merge will work in this case or not. you need to create array to add multiple values to it. as in this line you need an array $arr1[$arrkey][$subkey][]  to hold multiple values

```
$x1 = json_decode(json_encode($xmlobj), true);
$result = array();
function callarr ($arrin)
{            
foreach ($arrin as $arrkey => $arrvalue)
{
    foreach ($arrvalue as $subkey => $subvalue)
    {
        if (is_array($subvalue))
        {                               
            $arr1[$arrkey][$subkey][] = $subvalue;               
            // recursive function here
        }
        else
        {
            $arr2[$arrkey][0][$subkey][] = $subvalue;
        }
    }
    $result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);                
}
return $result;   
}
$x2 = callarr ($x1);
print_r ($x2);
```

Comment: Hi Amit Sharma, Thanks a lot for your response. Sorry I'm newbie here so I'll take longer time to combine your answers. The [ ] addition in $arr1[$arrkey][$subkey][] = $subvalue; will create the [0] if there's an array. This is correct, thank you. The [ ] addition in $arr2[$arrkey][0][$subkey][] = $subvalue; should be removed since it will create [0] for each value in array. For the first loop this is correct, but I've to do the same for the each node, meaning I have to call this function again for recursive each node. I don't know the depth of this array will be. Need some suggestions, thanks